# A task was canceled

Tags: c#, wpf

I am running a task. When closing the window i am trying to cancel the task using cancellation token source. The error does not occur every time the window is closed. Only sometimes. Please take a look at the error I am getting

[image]

```
    private CancellationTokenSource dotIndicatorTokenSource;
    private void BlinkDotIndicator()
    {

        var halfPeriod = 200;

        dotIndicatorTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    connectionIndicatorDotImg.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                });
                Thread.Sleep(halfPeriod);

                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    connectionIndicatorDotImg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                });

                Thread.Sleep(halfPeriod);

                if (dotIndicatorTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }, dotIndicatorTokenSource.Token);

    }


    private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dotIndicatorTokenSource != null)
            dotIndicatorTokenSource.Cancel();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run the code, check if the cancellation is pending before and after, and in between. That way you don't execute the next Dispatcher functions if it is cancelled during an operation.

```
        while (true)
        {
            if (dotIndicatorTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                connectionIndicatorDotImg.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            });
            Thread.Sleep(halfPeriod);

            if (dotIndicatorTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }

            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                connectionIndicatorDotImg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            });

            Thread.Sleep(halfPeriod);

            if (dotIndicatorTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Oh I see. Following that logic, is it really necessary to check for cancellation in the end then?

Comment: Eh. No? Not really. But it is after a sleep. So it doesn't really matter. Why not be safe. It's 4 lines of code. And you won't even go into your next loop.